# Linux no sound on headphone jack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio, headphone-jack

I am unable to get sound out of the headphone jack on my laptop while the speakers work properly, I`m running this;
HP Spectre X360 (13-w010nd x360)
Linux Lite 4.0 (based on Ubuntu 18 LTS)
Im not aware of any other audio software besides ALSA and PulseAudio

The sound output stops from the speakers when I plug in headphones (and I can confirm that the output port changes from 'speaker' to 'headphone' in alsamixer). When I last ran the laptop under Win10, the port worked, I can also confirm the headphones to be working on a different device (and these specific headphones worked under Win10 before).
Solutions I've tried are;
https://askubuntu.com/questions/829520/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound-from-speakers-only-headphones-working/929766 (I tried the reverse as well)
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114946
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161581

I have attempted to change the `analog-output-headphones.conf` file in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/` to no avail.
Running `pactl list | grep 'Active Port'` returns `analog-output-speaker` without headphones plugged in and `analog-output-headphones` with them plugged in. Also running `pactl list sinks` indicates that the active port switches between plugging in and out. Both seem to imply that jack insertion works as intended. I can't seem to find any indication of what would be wrong with my configuration.
I'd really like help with this! If there's anything else you'd like me to mention, let me know!

Comment: An idea: Did you unmute the headphones channel? (`alsamixer` -> find the headphone channel -> press `m`) Do you see any output being actually sent to the headphones? (`pauvcontrol` has volume meters under the `Output Devices` tab) This would be the simple fix, if that doesn't work for you please go [here](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug) and download the `alsa-info.sh` script and include the resulting link in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The mute/unmute has no effect. These are the results;
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1179c84bd75f2f15ac61aac5b4b48b6d321e1f04

Comment: Can you tell me if in `pauvcontrol` the VU meter is glowing when you play audio? I've had a similiar issue recently when pulse-audio wouldn't properly detect the soundcard. Your `pactl` output, which looks fine, confuses me though so it'd be important to know if the VU meter shows output or not.

Comment: The PUAVC gui shows both a line to set volume and one that corresponds to current output. port control changes from speakers headphones corresponding to whether something is plugged in or not. Hope this helps

Comment: And that line does move while audio is playing? In that case I'd rather suspect a hardware issue, but if it works in win10 that's weird. In my case the headphones wouldnt show up at all within `pauvcontrol`, and what worked for me is to manually put a `set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo` into `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` and then restarting pulseaudio. - You can try, but I doubt this will have any effect in your case since pulse-audio does seem to detect your audiocard properly.

Comment: Yes, sorry, thats what I meant with the last comment. The line moves, there is output. I also tried your fix anyway but it didnt have any effect (as expected?).

Comment: Out of my help range then, I'm sorry. I suspect a hardware issue. Can you try under win10 again somehow on the same device?

Comment: Same issue here with spectre x360 and fedora linux 28. Tried all the shit I can - OS detects sound card and there is sound when using notebook speakers, when I plug in something external like headphones/sound system in my audio port - it detects it but there is no sound coming out. Works on windows 10. Ideas?